# How to grant access from admin of a google apps domain

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have an application that will be published in google marketplace & that needs grant access from a domain administrator (`admin@domain.com`) to access drive rather than a simple user (`simple-user@gmail.com`) drive.

Is there a way to check if the user authenticated is an admin of a domain-wide delegation or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Only the domain super admin is allowed to install Marketplace applications for the domain.
If you try to access an admin only API, like any in the admin SDK you'll get a 403 Forbidden error, that can be another way to check.

However, if you need to really want to know if the current user is a super admin or a delegated admin, you can use the [Directory API part of the Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) to retrieve the user resource by its email and check the isAdmin and isDelegatedAdmin fields in order to know.